# GNU radio companion raw captured data file split

Tags: gnuradio

My file is a simple raw data 32 bit floats sampled at 384 kHz. No metadata or anything alike. The file is some 10+ GB. I am looking for a method of isolating a certain group of signals from it into a new raw data file. I know where the group starts and how long it lasts. How do I extract these few MB from the 10GB file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, beacause you know how large your single sample is (32 bit = 4 B), and since you know where your signal of interest starts and how long it lasts, this is just a matter of

- Converting that position and length knowledge to sample numbers (if you know it in *time* rather than samples; but it's easy; $n_{sample}= t_{sample}\cdot f_{sample}$)
- Multiplying that with the sample size
- Cutting the file at the appropriate places

If you're on a unixoid (or have `dd` for windows), then `dd` can do that for you, with the `bs` (blocksize), with `skip` you can skip the start of the input, and with `count=` you can define how much you want. So, something like, if you want the 1 million samples, starting at sample 12345678:

```
 dd if=/your/large/sample/file of=/path/to/output/file bs=4 skip=12345677 count=1000000
```

Of course, there's other ways, too. If you like Python, you could use `numpy` to open that file using `numpy.memmap`, which acts as if you could directly deal with the data on disk as if it was in RAM; that alleviates the need to have 10 GB of spare RAM just to skip the first 9 GB. `memmap` takes an offset argument and hence doesn't require seeking through the unintersting beginning, and `shape` can be set to the length you're interested in:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.memmap("/path/to/input", dtype=np.float32, offset=12345678, shape(1,1000000))
# maybe you'd even want to do some signal processing here?
arr.tofile("/path/to/output")
```

Of course, within GNU Radio:

Open the file with `file_source`, skip the beginning with the `skip_head` block, keep only what you want with the `head` block.

Comment: I have taken the `dd` route; tow amendments: pay attention to stereo channels (complex IQ in radio terms) anduse `ibs` for faster processing: `dd if=/your/large/sample/file of=/path/to/output/file ibs=8 skip=12345677 count=1000000`